# How to fix pgAdmin 4 url for postgresql launch

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have installed postgresql with installer and every time, I launch PgAdmin 4. I have different browser url to access to postgres interface. 
Ex: http://127.0.0.1:49832/browser/ or http://127.0.0.1:49521/browser/.

How can I fix the url? it will be easier to access to an url that I can add to favorites. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

pgAdmin4 will use random port when you use it as a Desktop application.

If you want to use the it with static port then configure it to run in Server mode.
Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.x/server_deployment.html#apache-httpd-configuration-linux-unix